# Custom layout for PagerTabStrip tabs

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the layout of PageTabStriper tabs. I need to move the selection indicator to the top and add divider between the tabs.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find the answer?

Comment: @2943 sorry it was a long time ago I don't remember properly. As far as I can remember I convinced clients to change the design :)

Comment: Thanks  for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own pager indicator how ever i recommend you use [this one](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Comment: PagerSlidingTabStrip doesn't behave like PageTabStrip. The selected tab isn't on centre.